# When to use `wire` in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

As far as I can tell in SystemVerilog the only reason to ever use `wire` is if you really need multiple drivers on the same net (e.g. for I2C). In every other situation `var` is strictly better because it warns you about accidental multiple drivers and it also supports procedural assignment. This is true for module inputs, outputs and members.

Is there any situation other than multiple drivers where it is better to use `wire` then `var`?

Comment: In system verilog you should use wires for 'inouts' and buses. Multiple drivers should not be used anywhere no matter what. Even for buses there must be only a single driver at the time.

Answer (score 0):

In RTL design, this is generally true. However, there are a few exceptions where using wires to convey strength information is still favorable, like in switch level modeling or power isolation.

Also note that input ports default to being wires, not variables. This is done for simulation performance reasons. When both the upper and lower levels of a port connection are wires, the port gets *collapsed* into a single wire. You would not want a high-frequency signal, such as a clock, to have to schedule assignments to different variables throughout the design hierarchy every time the clock toggles.

Comment: Interesting point but I don't see why simulators couldn't also do the "collapsing" for `input var`. In fact it should be easier since they don't have to worry about multiple drivers. Do you have a reference for this? I would have guessed that the reason `input` ports default to the default net type is for compatibility with Verilog in some way.

Comment: It is mostly described in sections _23.3.3.1 Port coercion_ and _23.3.3.7 Port connections with dissimilar net types (net and port collapsing)_. A port where one side is a variable cannot be coerced. This also means a `force` on a signal will not propagate though the port in the opposite direction. A simulator could optimize the port as long as it doesn't change the behavior.